# how to get sqlite connection properly?

Tags: java, android, database

If you can check the code and fix the errors in this code

**Home.java**

```
package com.;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText username_editText;
    EditText password_editText;
    Button loginbtn;
    Button registerbtn;

    public static final String USERID = "userID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        username_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_userName);
        password_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_password);
        loginbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_loginBtn);
        registerbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home_registerBtn);
        final DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(Home.this);

        registerbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.ProfileManagement");
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String userName = username_editText.getText().toString();
            String password = password_editText.getText().toString();

           if(userName.equals("") || password.equals("")){
               Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Login Unsuccessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else{
               UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(userName);

               if(users == null){
                   Toast.makeText(Home.this,"Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

               else{
                   int userID = users.getId();
                   Intent editProfIntent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.EditProfile");
                   editProfIntent.putExtra(USERID,Integer.toString(userID));
                   startActivity(editProfIntent);

               }
           }
        }
    });
}
```

I think there is error in db class I can't find this error.app is crashed db not created . please try to understand it

**DBHandler.java**

```
package com.;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, "user_db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE "+UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME +"( "+UserProfile.Users.COL_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"+UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME+" TEXT UNIQUE," +
            UserProfile.Users.COL_PASSWORD +" TEXT, "+UserProfile.Users.COL_GENDER +" TEXT, "+UserProfile.Users.COL_DOB +" TEXT"+")";

        Log.d("createQuery",createQuery);

        try {
            db.execSQL(createQuery);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE "+UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME +"( "+UserProfile.Users.COL_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"+UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME+" TEXT," +
            UserProfile.Users.COL_PASSWORD +" TEXT, "+UserProfile.Users.COL_GENDER +" TEXT, "+UserProfile.Users.COL_DOB+" TEXT"+")";

        Log.d("createQuery",createQuery);

        try {
            db.execSQL(createQuery);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public boolean addInfo(UserProfile.Users users){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO "+UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME+"("+UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME+","+UserProfile.Users.COL_PASSWORD+","+UserProfile.Users.COL_GENDER+","+
            UserProfile.Users.COL_DOB+") VALUES('"+users.getUsername()+"','"+users.getPassword()+"','"+users.getGender()+"','"+users.getDob()+"')";

        Log.d("insertQuery",insertQuery);

        try {
            db.execSQL(insertQuery);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
        }

        db.close();
        return false;
    }

    public boolean updateInfor(UserProfile.Users users){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String username = users.getUsername();
        String password = users.getPassword();
        String dob = users.getDob();
        String gender = users.getGender();
        int id = users.getId();
        values.put(UserProfile.Users.COL_DOB,dob);
        values.put(UserProfile.Users.COL_GENDER,gender);
        values.put(UserProfile.Users.COL_PASSWORD,password);
        values.put(UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME,username);

        int result = db.update(UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME,values,UserProfile.Users.COL_ID+" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

        if(result >0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }


    public ArrayList<UserProfile.Users> readAllInfor(){

        ArrayList<UserProfile.Users> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String readAllQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(readAllQuery,null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();

                users.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                users.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
                users.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
                users.setGender(cursor.getString(3));
                users.setDob(cursor.getString(4));

                userList.add(users);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return userList;

    }

    public UserProfile.Users readAllInfor(String userName){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String readSingleQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME + " =  '"+ userName+"'";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(readSingleQuery,null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

            UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();

            users.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            users.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            users.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
            users.setGender(cursor.getString(3));
            users.setDob(cursor.getString(4));

            return users;
        }

       return null;
    }

    public UserProfile.Users readAllInfor(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String readSingleQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ UserProfile.Users.COL_ID + " =  '"+ id+"'";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(readSingleQuery,null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

            UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();

            users.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            users.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            users.setPassword(cursor.getString(2));
            users.setGender(cursor.getString(3));
            users.setDob(cursor.getString(4));

            return users;
        }

        return null;
    }



    public void deleteInfo(String username){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM "+ UserProfile.Users.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ UserProfile.Users.COL_USERNAME +" = '"+ username +"' ";
        Log.d("deleteQuery ",deleteQuery);
        db.execSQL(deleteQuery);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

I checked this one and couldn't find the solution for solve it. This is user profile class to handle user profiles.

**UserProfile.java**

```
package com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002;

public final class UserProfile {

    private UserProfile(){

    }

    public static UserProfile getProfile(){

        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
        return userProfile;
    }
    class Users implements BaseColumn{

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "UserInfo";
        public static final String COL_ID = "_ID";
        public static final String COL_USERNAME  = "userName ";
        public static final String COL_DOB = "dateOfBirth";
        public static final String COL_GENDER = "Gender";
        public static final String COL_PASSWORD = "Password";


        //displya karana ona variable tika
        private int id;
        private String username;
        private String dob;
        private String gender;
        private String password;


        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getDob() {
            return dob;
        }

        public void setDob(String dob) {
            this.dob = dob;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
    //hethuwa-wena thanaka class ekaka wena wenama varible cll krnnaq ona unoth
    public Users getUser(){
        Users users = new Users();

        return users;
    }
}
```

This is edit profile class i have doubt of this class.

**EditProfile.java**

```
 package com.;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.RadioButton;
 import android.widget.RadioGroup;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button searchBtn;
    EditText userName_editText;
    EditText password_editText;
    EditText dob_editText;
    RadioGroup genderRadioGroup;
    RadioButton genderRadioBtn;

    //new Edit
    RadioButton genderRadioBtnMale;
    RadioButton genderRadioBtnFemale;

    Button editBtn;
    Button deleteBtn;
    Intent intent;
    DBHandler dbHandler;

    public static final String USERID_EDITPROFILE = "userID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        searchBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_searchbtn);
        userName_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_userName);
        password_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_password);
        dob_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editprof_dob);
        genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.editprof_radiogroup);
        editBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_editbtn);
        deleteBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editprof_deletebtn);


        //new edit
        genderRadioBtnMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.editprof_male_radio);
        genderRadioBtnFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.editprof_female_radio);

        intent = getIntent();


        dbHandler = new DBHandler(EditProfile.this);

        setUserDetails();

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();

                if(username == null){
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter username to delete your profile",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(username);

                    if(users == null){
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"No profile found from this username, please enter valid username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        dbHandler.deleteInfo(username);
                        Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent(EditProfile.this,Home.class);
                        startActivity(redirectintent_home);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String userID_String = intent.getStringExtra(Home.USERID);
                if(userID_String == null){

Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Error!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     Intent redirectintent_home =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                    startActivity(redirectintent_home);
                }
               int userID = Integer.parseInt(userID_String);

                String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();
                String password = password_editText.getText().toString();
                String dob = dob_editText.getText().toString();
                int selectedGender = genderRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                genderRadioBtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedGender);
                String gender = genderRadioBtn.getText().toString();

                UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();
                users.setUsername(username);
                users.setPassword(password);
                users.setDob(dob);
                users.setGender(gender);
                users.setId(userID);

                dbHandler.updateInfor(users);
                Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
                startActivity(redirectintent_home);
            }
        });

        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               String username = userName_editText.getText().toString();
               if (username == null){
                   Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter a username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else{
                   UserProfile.Users users_search = dbHandler.readAllInfor(username);


                   if(users_search == null){
                       Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Please enter a valid username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   else{
                       userName_editText.setText(users_search.getUsername());
                       password_editText.setText(users_search.getPassword());
                       dob_editText.setText(users_search.getDob());
                       int id = users_search.getId();
                       Intent redirectintent = new Intent(EditProfile.this,EditProfile.class);

redirectintent.putExtra(USERID_EDITPROFILE,Integer.toString(id));
                       startActivity(redirectintent);
                   }
               }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setUserDetails(){

        String userID_String = intent.getStringExtra(Home.USERID);
        if(userID_String == null){
            Toast.makeText(EditProfile.this,"Error!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent redirectintent_home = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.Home");
        startActivity(redirectintent_home);
        }
        int userID = Integer.parseInt(userID_String);
        UserProfile.Users users = dbHandler.readAllInfor(userID);
        userName_editText.setText(users.getUsername());
        password_editText.setText(users.getPassword());
        dob_editText.setText(users.getDob());

        //new edit
        String gender = users.getGender();
        if(gender.equals("Male")){
            genderRadioBtnMale.setChecked(true);
            genderRadioBtnFemale.setChecked(false);
        }
        else{
            genderRadioBtnMale.setChecked(false);
            genderRadioBtnFemale.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

if you can try to check this also

**ProfileManagement.java**

```
package com.;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProfileManagement extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username_editText;
    EditText password_editText;
    EditText dob_editText;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton gender_radioBtn;
    Button saveProfBtn;

    public final static String USERID_PROFILEMGMT = "userID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_management);

        username_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_userName);
        password_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_password);
        dob_editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_dob);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_radiogroup);
        saveProfBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.profmgmt_btn);
        final DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(ProfileManagement.this);

        saveProfBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String username = username_editText.getText().toString();
                String password = password_editText.getText().toString();
                String dob = dob_editText.getText().toString();
                int selectedGender = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                gender_radioBtn = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedGender);
                String gender = gender_radioBtn.getText().toString();

                UserProfile.Users users = UserProfile.getProfile().getUser();
                users.setUsername(username);
                users.setPassword(password);
                users.setDob(dob);
                users.setGender(gender);
                boolean result = dbHandler.addInfo(users);

                if(result ==  true){
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileManagement.this,"Successfully added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    UserProfile.Users newusers = dbHandler.readAllInfor(username);
                    int userID = newusers.getId();
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.modelpaper.mad.it17121002.EditProfile");
                    intent.putExtra(USERID_PROFILEMGMT,Integer.toString(userID));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, please look at this [guide how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The problem with your question is that it is a lot of code someone has to read in order to help you. please shorten it so that people can help you easier.

Comment: package com.testapp.modelpaper;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button reg;
    private Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regbtn);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updatebtn);

        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                regclick();
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginclick();
            }
        });
    }

Comment: private void loginclick() {
        Intent it = new Intent(this,EditProfile.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }

    private void regclick() {
        Intent it = new Intent(this,ProfileManagement.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "student.db";

 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";

 public static final String COL1 = "ID";

 public static final String COL2 = "NAME";

 public static final String COL3 = "SURNAME"

 ;
 public static final String COL4 = "MARKS";

 ​

 public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

  // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); }

  ​

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

   db.execSQL(" create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)");

  }

  @Override

  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

   onCreate(db);

  }

  public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String marks) {

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

   ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

   contentValues.put(COL2, name);

   contentValues.put(COL3, surname);

   contentValues.put(COL4, marks);

   long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

   if (result == -1)

    return false;

   else

    return true;

  }

  public Cursor getAlldata() {

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

   Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);

   return res;
  }

 }

 ​

 public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String surname, String marks) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

  contentValues.put(COL1, id);

  contentValues.put(COL2, name);

  contentValues.put(COL3, surname);

  contentValues.put(COL4, marks);

  db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] {
   id
  });
  return true;
 }
}

​

public Integer deleteData(String id) {

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

 return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ? ", new String[] {
  id
 });
}

​

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 public Button but1;

 ​

 DatabaseHelper myDb;

 EditText editName, editSurname, editMarks, editTextid;

 Button btnAddData;

 Button btnViewall;

 ​

 public void init() {

   but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

   but1.setOnClickListener(

    new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override

     public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent my = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
      startActivity(my);
     }
    });

   ​

   @Override

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);

    editSurname = (EditText) findViewById((R.id.editText_surname));

    editMarks = (EditText) findViewById((R.id.editText_marks));

    editTextid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_id);

    btnAddData = (Button) findViewById((R.id.button_add));

    btnViewall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_view);

    Adddata();

    viewAll();

    update();

   }

   public void Adddata() {

    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(

     new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override

      public void onClick(View v) {

       boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(), editSurname.getText().toString(), editMarks.getText().toString());

       if (isInserted == true)

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       else

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
     });
   }

   ​

   public void update() {

     btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(

       new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

         boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateData(editTextid.getText().toString(), editName.getText().toString(), editSurname.getText().toString(), editMarks.getText().toString());

         if (isUpdate == true)

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         else

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
       }

       ​

       public void Delete() {

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(

         new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override

          public void onClick(View v) {

           Integer deleteRows = myDb.deleteData(editTextid.getText().toString());

           if (deleteRows > 0)

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
         });
       }

       ​

       ​

       public void viewAll() {

        btnViewall.setOnClickListener(

          new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override

           public void onClick(View v) {

             Cursor res = myDb.getAlldata();

             if (res.getCount() == 0) {

              return;

             }

             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

             while (res.moveToNext()) {

              buffer.append("id :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");

              buffer.append("name :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");

              buffer.append("surname: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");

              buffer.append("marks: " + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Code only answers doesn't provide any help. Best practice is put some description what are you doing here and what is the thing which will solve the problem
Spend some time reading [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Try this one also

Answer (score -1):

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "student.db";

public static final String TABLE_NAME ="student_table";

public static final String COL1 = "ID";

public static final String COL2 = "NAME";

public static final String COL3 = "SURNAME"

; public static final String COL4 = "MARKS";

​

public DatabaseHelper( Context context) {

super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);

// SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); }

​

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

db.execSQL( " create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SURNAME TEXT, MARKS INTEGER)" );

}

@Override

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME );

onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String marks){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put(COL2,name);

contentValues.put(COL3,surname);

contentValues.put(COL4,marks);

long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

if(result == -1)

return false;

else

return true;

}

public Cursor getAlldata(){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null );

return res; }

}

​

public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String surname, String marks){ SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put(COL1,id);

contentValues.put(COL2,name);

contentValues.put(COL3,surname);

contentValues.put(COL4,marks);

db.update(TABLE_NAME , contentValues, "ID = ?",new String[]{ id }); return true; } }

​

public Integer deleteData(String id){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

return db.delete(TABLE_NAME , "ID = ? ", new String[]{id}); }

​

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button but1;

​

DatabaseHelper myDb;

EditText editName, editSurname, editMarks,editTextid;

Button btnAddData;

Button btnViewall;

​

public void init(){

but1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);

but1.setOnClickListener(

new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) { Intent my = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class); startActivity(my); } } );

​

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_name);

editSurname = (EditText)findViewById((R.id.editText_surname));

editMarks = (EditText)findViewById((R.id.editText_marks));

editTextid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_id);

btnAddData= (Button)findViewById((R.id.button_add));

btnViewall=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_view);

Adddata();

viewAll();

update();

}

public void Adddata(){

btnAddData.setOnClickListener(

new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData( editName.getText().toString(), editSurname.getText().toString(), editMarks.getText().toString() );

if(isInserted == true)

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,"Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

else

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } } ); }

​

public void update(){

btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(

new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateData(editTextid.getText().toString(), editName.getText().toString(), editSurname.getText().toString(), editMarks.getText().toString() );

if(isUpdate == true)

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

else

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Updated" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } }

​

public void Delete(){

btnDelete.setOnClickListener(

new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

Integer deleteRows = myDb.deleteData(editTextid.getText().toString());

if(deleteRows > 0)

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Data Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } } ); }

​

​

public void viewAll(){

btnViewall.setOnClickListener(

new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

Cursor res= myDb.getAlldata();

if(res.getCount() == 0){

return;

}

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while(res.moveToNext()){

buffer.append("id :" + res.getString(0)+ "\n");

buffer.append("name :" + res.getString(1)+ "\n");

buffer.append("surname: " + res.getString(2) +"\n");

buffer.append("marks: " + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");

public final class UserProfile {

```
private UserProfile(){

}

public static UserProfile getProfile(){

    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
    return userProfile;
}
class Users implements BaseColumn{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "UserInfo";
    public static final String COL_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String COL_USERNAME  = "userName ";
    public static final String COL_DOB = "dateOfBirth";
    public static final String COL_GENDER = "Gender";
    public static final String COL_PASSWORD = "Password";

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String dob;
    private String gender;
    private String password;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}

public Users getUser(){
    Users users = new Users();

    return users;
}
```

}

Comment: Please format your code properly, it's not very readable as it is. By the looks of it you need to shift everything by four spaces to correct the mistake. Also note that code-only answers are discouraged, the answer will have more long-term value if you explain why and how this solution works.

Answer (score -2):

seems this codeline works properly and there anrent any issues please implement it and check it..
well done